# How do you add a UINavigationBar to UIWebView such that the web content draw area scales to the area beneath the navigation bar?

Tags: uiview, ios4, uiwebview, uinavigationbar

Here's the situation:

myViewController has a button called "Help." Pressing "Help" activates the following IBAction method, which loads a UIWebView displaying a PDF. It also loads a subView into that UIWebView that is a UINavigationBar called "helpNavBar" with a "Done" button. The reason I load the helpNavBar programmatically is because if I don't do that, then the helpNavBar gets covered over by the PDF display (although you can still see it if you scroll the PDF down far enough to uncover it...!). However, **the problem is this:** even after loading helpNavBar programmatically, **the PDF still scales to the full screen area (except now it does so *beneath* the helpNavBar instead of on top of it).**

Here is my code for the IBAction method:

```
 (IBAction)helpButtonPress:(id)sender {
    UIView *current_view;
    current_view = self.view;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"switch" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];
    //[current_view removeFromSuperview];

    //STILL CAN'T GET THE HELP PDF TO SHOW PROPERLY (IT IS PARTIALLY UNDER THE BUTTON)
    self.helpView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.helpView.autoresizesSubviews = TRUE;
    [self.helpView addSubview:helpNavBar];
    [helpNavBar setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

    [self.view addSubview:helpView];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Angle of View Manual" ofType:@"pdf"];
    if (thePath) {
        NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
        [self.helpView loadData:pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf"
                        textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
    }
}
```

I should note: I also had this same problem when my UITableViewController would load. However in that case, I created a UIView with two subViews: one for the tableView and one for a navBar. That way the tableView didn't cover over the navBar. *I know I could also do that in this case, but I feel like that's a kludgy way to do it and there must be an easier/better way to do something as simple as having the interface and PDF view areas not draw all over each other like two-year-olds at a felt marker convention.* But if the only way to do it is to "keep 'em separated" in separate subViews of a master UIView, then just tell me to "pay no mind" ... I won't take any "disrespect."

PS -- I was avoiding using a separate UIViewController for this basic. The view just needs to pop up and show a brief PDF and have a 'done' button, that's it. If there's an even easier way to do this then please, pipe up :D

Comment: Why does creating the UIWebView and the UINavigationBar as subviews of a container seem kludgy to you? If you don't want them to overlap, don't make them overlap..

Comment: Are you definitively saying there's no other way to doit? I guess I thought the webView could have a bounds within which to render the content.

Comment: BTW I do think it's kludgy to have to use three aspects (view with two subviews) instead of two aspects (view with one subview). Why is there even the option of adding a navBar inside a UIWebView if it can't "wrap" its web content around it? I mean.. to me that seems kludgy.. for software to let you try to do something that you were never meant to be able to do. I assume because it lets me do it then there must be a way to do it this way and have it work right. Am I wrong?